# Using wordpress as external content management system

Tags: asp.net, wordpress, api, content-management-system

We are planning to create an asp.net website (probably mvc), that needs a cms for news items.

Our content managers and others who require to publish news have asked if they can use wordpress for content management.

Our users have different roles, and news items should be visible to certain roles, or even specific users if possible.

The reason they want wordpress is the manager's user friendliness, so if some other alternative with the same kind of user experience would be ok.

Could anyone please point me in some direction?

**NOTE: I'm still doing research at the moment, so I've got nothing holding me back at this point.**

Answer (score 1):

There is an API plugin that has been developed to spit out information in JSON, but I have not actually implemented a site with it:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/json-api/

Perhaps you could have the authors work on a wordpress install and create your app to draw content via that plugin?

Comment: FWIW, I've spent the last week or so using that plugin.  I've had to write some controllers to get it to spit out custom content, but it more or less works as you'd expect, plus it has a nice set of models that, for instance, output all the attachments for a post.

Comment: Since I'm working with .net I decided to go with blogengine.net as it's much easier to integrate without the learning curve of both the wordpress framework and php.

thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 1):

I too was facing the same issue, little different. We want to have WP as CMS so that our site can take the benefit of SEO which is very easy with WP. SO we installed WP under a folder in the Main ASP.net based website. Initially there were issues, I was unable to run it.  Finally managed to run it. Solution is posted here - http://www.wwwlabz.com/how-to-run-a-php-based-website-from-a-subfolder-in-asp-net-website. Hope it will help someone. Actual site where we implemented this is http://www.periproperties.com/content/.

Now I want to have specific section of WP to be accessible on my site. SO I am exploring different options and will post, if found something

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[DotNetNuke](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/) is the most popular ASP.NET based CMS ([source](http://w3techs.com/technologies/overview/content_management/all)).  I am implementing my first project in it and so far I am very happy with it.

Note the free edition will not work for you since you need customizable security roles and free has a limited set of predetermined roles.  You'll need the pro edition.

I don't know how similar it is to WordPress.  Overall, WordPress is much more popular but of course there are platform issues with WordPress since it is Apache based and you want to create an ASP.NET website.

Comment: Well I don't mind having to host the wordpress content somewhere else really. I've had a look at DotNetNuke, but always got mixed responses about it.

Comment: It sounds like you know WordPress and are set on using it.  Why ask the question then?

Comment: Actually, I don't know wordpress that much, and it's my bosses that are set on using it.

I'm asking, maybe this has been done before using wordpress, so everyone will be happy..